# Generosity has generous. What is the equivalent for animosity?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

A so-called friend of mine once thanked me for my animosity. Animosity is a noun in this usage. What is the adjective associated with animosity? I guess there isn't one. But what is the closest word to my requirement. Also - and this is perhaps a separate question - what percentage of words that are nouns do not have an adjectival form?

Answer (score 1):

Animosity is also *hostility*. As such, **hostile** is the adjective you want in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really want to keep with the word *animosity*, it seems there is actually a word you can use (although I hadn't heard of it until 2 minutes ago and *hostile* is certainly a better word):

***animose*** (via thefreedictionary.com):

> Full of spirit; hot; vehement; resolute.

Comment: animose isn't derived from animosity though, although they do ultimately share the same Latin root: [animosus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/animosus).